# Recover my history of past commands?

Tags: bash, command-history

Always when I turn on my Fedora 18, my history command disappear.

How can I recovery all my history since I installed my OS?

In my ./bash_history show olny the command of the day when I turn off my PC disappear all my past command in ./bash_history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot recover it, sorry.

For unlimited Bash history consult [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/137438/how-to-unlimited-bash-shell-history), and if you stall somewhere, edit your question in detail to help you out.

In short, if they do not already exist, you should add two lines to your `.bashrc`:

```
HISTSIZE=
HISTFILESIZE=
```

If your username is vitor, under normal configuration the full path of `.bashrc` will be `/home/vitor/.bashrc`.

Comment: Ok, but how can I make this? Disappear all the history command and in ./bash_history? And how can I stop the history disappear?

Comment: In my basrc is # .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

Comment: Since I do not see any `HISTSIZE=` or `HISTFILESIZE=` lines, you can add those two lines at the end of the file. Do not add anything after the equal sign (=). For verification, start a new shell and type a few commands. Watch how `.bash_history` changes appending the command you just wrote. You should be able to keep the history after reboot. Try it and let us know. ;)