# Issue with zsh segfaulting: how to further assess the issue?

Tags: zsh, segmentation-fault

I'm using *Linux arch* 3.15.2-1-ARCH x86_64. I don't use `zsh` (zsh-5.0.5-1) every day, otherwise I would have noticed it *segfaults*, when I launch it from the `bash` cli:

```
arch kernel: zsh[2187]: segfault at 8 ip 00007f3b49853083 sp 00007fff2ad39198 error 4 in libc-2.19.so[7f3b497d2000+1a4000]
arch systemd-coredump[2188]: Process 2187 (zsh) dumped core.
```

Now I remember running it at some point and going through the configuration script(`zsh /usr/share/zsh/functions/Newuser/zsh-newuser-install -f` segfaults too now). So I have done the following:

- Reboot
- The behavior is the same in X or the console
- *Remove* with configuration and clear package cache, then *reinstall*: `pacman -Rns zsh; paccache -r; paccache -ruk0; pacman -S zsh`.
- Try to *compile* using the recipe for *5.0.5-1* and *5.0.4-1*: compiles, then goes on to check the binary by executing it, which segfaults in both cases, so this aborts.
- Made sure to *have no* `.zsh*` file in my home directory - made sure to *have* the [basic](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/zsh#Configuration_files) `.zsh*` files in my home dir.
- Renamed `/etc/profile`
- Renamed `/etc/zsh/zprofile`
- *zsh-completions* is/is not installed

Ironically, `zsh --version` or `--help` **work** and echo the relevant info.

So what could be the issue with my setup/environment here?

---

<sup>Note: ran [quick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/132193/44370) *gdb* if that brings any insight into what is happening:</sup>

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/bin/zsh 
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for linux-vdso.so.1.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff713e083 in __strchr_sse2 () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff713e083 in __strchr_sse2 () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000000044f2e3 in ?? ()
#2  0x000000000044f7d4 in op ()
#3  0x000000000045003b in ?? ()
#4  0x00000000004505cd in ?? ()
#5  0x00000000004507dc in matheval ()
#6  0x0000000000450829 in mathevali ()
#7  0x00000000004602b0 in ?? ()
#8  0x00000000004624ab in assignsparam ()
#9  0x0000000000463636 in createparamtable ()
#10 0x000000000043f2b5 in setupvals ()
#11 0x0000000000440e14 in zsh_main ()
#12 0x00007ffff70dd000 in __libc_start_main () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#13 0x000000000040f7be in _start ()
```

Comment: I'd use `strace zsh` to see what's going on.

Comment: @slm Thank you for the suggestion. I put that [there](http://pastebin.com/PaCJbR3r). I see a few errors like an illegal lseek and some files not found but I'm afraid I can't see anything meaningful at my level..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior can be reproduced with:

```
export HISTSIZE=V=
```

For some reason I had that in my *.bashrc* file. Most likely I didn't have focus in the window I thought I had, ended up adding V= without noticing it and was careless saving the file; maybe it was open in the editor - those are set to enable [unlimited history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/132260/44370). But *zsh* uses the parameter [too](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-HISTSIZE). So *bash* didn't complain about the error but *zsh* did... A quick look at the output of `env`for anything unusual has to be on the debug checklist.

Comment: Since that's a setting for interactive bash shells with a syntax specific to bash shells, it should be put in `~/.bashrc` and not exported as opposed to exported in `~/.profile`. Same as for PS1 where the syntax is shell specific but the variable is shared by different shells.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you, I will remember this lesson about the environment for sure! That's one for my books. Although I must say even without exporting here, just having that typo in the parameter value triggers the segfault.